# Visual studio code extend and style syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you extend the syntax of a language in visual studio code?

I want vs code to accept arguments with a set of types in javascript such as:

function setName(**String** name)

Then I want to color these types whenever they are used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code allows you to define custom styles and syntax rules. The latter can be done by defining your own set of grammar with the help of regular expressions. You might also want to read about TextMate.
Check the link below:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers

Comment: Thanks it really helps.